# Typo on the MCVE page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, minimal-reproducible-example, typographical-error

Just a small thing, but there is inconsistency in the dash width on the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) page:

> [image]

For those who can't see the minuscule difference (it's the hyphen after "Verifiable").

Who can fix this, and how do we get them to know about it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, thanks for editing that **typo**. Get it? :D

Comment: Uh, can you highlight the typo? I cannot see it and I doubt people in charge will fire up their diff tool.

Comment: @nvoigt It's the "hyphen" after "Verifiable" ;)

Comment: Wh.... this post is a screenshot of itself... what?

Comment: Wow, on Wikipedia MCVE is occupied by some credit card processing computer software library, but they now refer to here, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mcve, for the more common meaning... But frankly, [the LaTeX site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) (our typesetting site, that is) has [the better description](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231).

Comment: "Just a small thing" that's slightly smaller than it ought to be.

Comment: @DanGetz, it's just a small thing that got +24 ;).

Comment: Its more that you get +30 (at the time of writing) for your super hero vision.

Comment: A (fixed) typo in a post about a typo that contains an image of itself. Are we going fractal today?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi, not my idea :D.

Comment: Which one should it be? [Em dash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/em_dash#Noun)? ([en dash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_dash#Noun) seems unlikely—[CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style) 6.78: *"the principal use of the en dash is to connect numbers"* and *"...The en dash can be used in place of a hyphen in a compound adjective..."*).

Comment: cont'—[Kristen McQuillin](https://medium.com/@mediatinker/em-dashes-no-spaces-please-aa0eb17fd404): *"...new writers, stop using* ***spaces around em dashes.*** *They don’t belong there. Go ahead and put spaces around en dashes; use spaces with hyphens if you must. But leave the em dash closed."*

Comment: Though it may depend on the medium and [accessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_accessibility) considerations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've replaced the dash with the same [en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) used in the other points.

Comment: The fact that a bunch of people don't know how to punctuate properly doesn't mean that those who do shouldn't. That way madness lies. @rad

Comment: @Oded while you are at it, there are also several hyphens in the text which are inconsistent (long in "the problem disappears – then add the last part back" and short in "shortcut for formatting code - find it, and use it! Also, don't use tabs - they may").

Comment: All might powerful person to the rescue! ;)